# PL/pgSQL - insert multiple rows, returning the ids in a resultset

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am using PostgreSQL 8.4. My goal is to insert multiple rows with the help of PL/pgSQL and return the `id`-s of the inserted records back in a recordset.

At first I tried to do it in a single row, using the following code for my `permission_create(..)` function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION permission_create(
  IN method   permission.permission_method % TYPE,
  IN resource permission.permission_resource % TYPE
)
  RETURNS TABLE(id permission.permission_id % TYPE)
AS
  $BODY$
  BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
      WITH inserted_permission AS (
        INSERT INTO permission (permission_id, permission_method, permission_resource) VALUES (DEFAULT, method, resource)
        RETURNING permission_id
      )
      SELECT
        inserted_permission.permission_id AS id
      FROM inserted_permission;
  END;
  $BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

However, I got the following error message:

```
[2013-07-04 17:38:01] [00000] type reference permission.permission_method%TYPE converted to character varying
[2013-07-04 17:38:01] [00000] type reference permission.permission_resource%TYPE converted to character varying
[2013-07-04 17:38:01] [00000] type reference permission.permission_id%TYPE converted to integer
[2013-07-04 17:38:01] [00000] type reference permission.permission_id%TYPE converted to integer
[2013-07-04 17:38:01] [42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near "INSERT"
  Where: SQL statement in PL/PgSQL function "permission_create" near line 9
```

How should I fix this? Is there a way to do this in multiple lines?

**Solution:**

```
CREATE FUNCTION permission_create(
  IN method   permission.permission_method % TYPE,
  IN resource permission.permission_resource % TYPE
)
  RETURNS TABLE (id INT)
AS
  $BODY$
  BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
    INSERT INTO permission (permission_id, permission_method, permission_resource)
      VALUES (DEFAULT, method, resource)
    RETURNING permission_id;
  END;
  $BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updateable CTE is supported from PostgreSQL 9.1.

you don't need use CTE (in your case)

```
postgres=# CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fx()
RETURNS SETOF int AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY INSERT INTO taba(a) VALUES(1),(2)
    RETURNING *;
  RETURN;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
CREATE FUNCTION
postgres=# select * from fx();
 fx 
----
  1
  2
(2 rows)
```